# Use polars to read many small json files from S3 in parallel

Tags: python, dataframe, amazon-s3, python-polars

I have seen the following polars documentation:
https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/multiple_files/intro.html#reading-and-processing-in-parallel

Is there a way to create a query plan to read many small json files from an S3 bucket?

This would be similar to the way Spark can read many small json files or csv files from a single S3 prefix (path) with

```
spark.read.format("json").load("s3a://my-bucket/path/to/smallfiles/*.json")
```

Comment: Even passing a list of files to read and then reading those would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

## Parallel reading of many files from S3 with Polars

### Asynchronous JSON file retrieval and concatenation from Amazon S3 using Python [`polars`](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/getting-started/), [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html), and [`aiobotocore`](https://aiobotocore.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Here is an example reading from a public AWS S3 data bucket from [aws.amazon.com/opendata](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-zpajhdz2eccoo?sr=0-4&ref_=beagle&applicationId=AWSMPContessa#overview)¹:

```py
import io

import asyncio
import polars as pl

from aiobotocore.session import get_session
from botocore import UNSIGNED # NOTE: See Credentials＊ below.
from botocore.config import Config


S3_REGION = "eu-west-2"
S3_BUCKET = "pansurg-curation-raw-open-data"
S3_PREFIX = "cord19/AWSCORD19/upload_date=1591730933/"


async def read_json_from_s3(bucket, prefix):
    # Initialize S3 client
    session = get_session()
    async with session.create_client(
        "s3", region_name=S3_REGION, config=Config(signature_version=UNSIGNED)
    ) as client:
        file_limit = int(1e2) # NOTE: For demo purposes only.² (See endnotes)
        file_count = 0
        paginator = client.get_paginator("list_objects_v2")
        async for result in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix):
            contents = result.get("Contents", [])
            for obj in contents:
                key = obj["Key"]
                if key.endswith(".json"):
                    file_count += 1
                    if file_count > file_limit:
                        break
                    response = await client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
                    data = await response["Body"].read()
                    df = pl.read_json(io.StringIO(data.decode("utf-8")))
                    yield df


async def retrieve_json():
    bucket = S3_BUCKET
    prefix = S3_PREFIX

    # Read JSON files in parallel
    dfs = [df async for df in read_json_from_s3(bucket, prefix)]

    combined_df = pl.concat(dfs)

    return combined_df


df = asyncio.run(retrieve_json())
```

where

```py
print(df)
df.glimpse(max_items_per_column=1)
```

then gives:

```
shape: (100, 2)
┌───────────────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────┐
│ Attributes                        ┆ Title                             │
│ ---                               ┆ ---                               │
│ struct[4]                         ┆ str                               │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ {"cord19","txt","2020-06-08/docu… ┆ Absence of surface expression of… │
│ {"cord19","txt","2020-06-08/docu… ┆ Rethinking high-risk groups in C… │
│ {"cord19","txt","2020-06-08/docu… ┆ Plasma inflammatory cytokines an… │
│ {"cord19","txt","2020-06-08/docu… ┆ Seasonal influenza risk in hospi… │
│ {"cord19","txt","2020-06-08/docu… ┆ Disaster Perceptions              │
│ …                                 ┆ …                                 │
│ {"cord19","txt","2020-06-08/docu… ┆ A Global Survey on the Impact of… │
│ {"cord19","txt","2020-06-08/docu… ┆ Liver Chemistries in Patients wi… │
│ {"cord19","txt","2020-06-08/docu… ┆ Simulations for epidemiology and… │
│ {"cord19","txt","2020-06-08/docu… ┆ Expression and purification of c… │
│ {"cord19","txt","2020-06-08/docu… ┆ Transmissible gastroenteritis vi… │
└───────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────┘
Rows: 100
Columns: 2
$ Attributes <struct[4]> {'_category': 'cord19', '_file_type': 'txt', 'source_file': '2020-06-08/document_parses/pmc_json/PMC7127496.xml.json', 'publisher_url': 'https://api.elsevier.com/content/article/pii/S0378113506004792;https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17188823/;https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378113506004792'}
$ Title            <str> 'Absence of surface expression of feline infectious peritonitis virus (FIPV) antigens on infected cells isolated from cats with FIP'
```

#### Implementation Notes

- <sup>＊</sup>**Credentials**: No access tokens are needed for public-facing buckets. The [`boto3` equivalent of the AWS CLI "`aws s3 [command] --no-sign-request`"](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1200) is thus used.

---

<sub>¹ Data from **The REaltime DAta Synthesis and Analysis (REDASA) COVID-19 snapshot** was chosen as an example dataset because it met the criteria of containing many small JSON files. ² In the example above, a file limit of 100 was used during development and debug of the code.</sub>